# Unable to verify phone number is in file

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I'm developing an text message marketing service. In order to subscribe to my service, the user must text the keyword `memphis`. I've already written the code to add the users number to my subscriber's list, but if someone's number is already on the list, how can I include a process to check the already existing list and reply back with a message informing the user that they are already subscribed?

I have tried using a for loop to iterate over every number in the csv file:

```
def sms_subscription():
    contact_num = request.values.get('From')
    response = request.values.get('Body')
    resp = MessagingResponse()

   #NEW SUBSCRIBERS
    if response.lower() == 'memphis':
       with open('Subscriber_List.csv', 'r+') as subscriber_list:
           subscriber_list_writer = csv.writer(subscriber_list)
           for contact in subscriber_list:
               if contact == contact_num:
                   resp.message("Your already subscribed")
                   return str(resp)

               else:
                   subscriber_list_writer.writerow([contact_num])
                   resp.message("Thanks for subscribing to our local coupon book. As we get new deals, we'll notify via SMS. To opt-out reply 'STOP'")
                   return str(resp)

    else:
        resp.message("Be sure to check spelling and for spaces and try again.")
        return str(resp
```

I've tested this with my personal cell phone. Instead of replying back to me that my number is already subscribed, I continue to get the "Thanks for subscribing to our local coupon book.

As we get new deals, we'll notify the user via SMS. To opt-out, the user would reply 'STOP'.

Comment: So, the csv file just has a phone number on each line?

Comment: @MarsNebulaSoup yes

Comment: Try printing out `repr(contact)`. I imagine you'll find that each line has whitespace that you need to strip.

Comment: does `if new_number in list_of_numbers_already` not work?

Answer (score -1):

I think I see the problem.

Your code:

```py
def sms_subscription():
    contact_num = request.values.get('From')
    response = request.values.get('Body')
    resp = MessagingResponse()

   #NEW SUBSCRIBERS
    if response.lower() == 'memphis':
       with open('Subscriber_List.csv', 'r+') as subscriber_list:
           subscriber_list_writer = csv.writer(subscriber_list)
           for contact in subscriber_list:
               if contact == contact_num:
                   resp.message("Your already subscribed")
                   return str(resp)

               else:
                   subscriber_list_writer.writerow([contact_num])
                   resp.message("Thanks for subscribing to our local coupon book. As we get new deals, we'll notify via SMS. To opt-out reply 'STOP'")
                   return str(resp)

    else:
        resp.message("Be sure to check spelling and for spaces and try again.")
        return str(resp
```

First off, you should change `subscriber_list` to `subscriber_list.readlines()` to get a list in which each line is an element.

In your for loop you check if `contact` equals `contact_num`, but `contact` contains a newline (`\n`) (in my case when I tested it, but it may contain whitespaces or other chars), and thus is not equal to `contact_num`. To fix this, you can add these lines (there are one-liners to do this, with regex for example, but I'm using this example for readability and simplicity) above `if contact == contact_num`:

```
contact = contact.replace('\n','')
contact = contact.replace(' ','')
```

What these do is replace newlines and whitespaces with nothing, essentially removing them.

Furthermore, in your for loop, you are checking if `contact_num` is in the file, but if it is not the first element, then it will run this:

```
else:
    subscriber_list_writer.writerow([contact_num])
    resp.message("Thanks for subscribing to our local coupon book. As we get new deals, we'll notify via SMS. To opt-out reply 'STOP'")
    return str(resp)
```

What you need is to check ***all*** elements in the file, and then, if the number was not found, write it to the file. When you return a value, it exits the function, so if the first element in your file is not the desired phone number, then it will run your code under `else` and exit the function.

To fix this, just move

```
else:
    subscriber_list_writer.writerow([contact_num])
    resp.message("Thanks for subscribing to our local coupon book. As we get new deals, we'll notify via SMS. To opt-out reply 'STOP'")
    return str(resp)
```

outside of the for loop, and remove the `else`-- it is not needed. The loop will now check to see if `contact_num` is in the file, and if it is, it will return

`"You're already subscribed"`,

if not, it will add the num to the file and return

`"Thanks for subscribing to our local coupon book. As we get new deals, we'll notify via SMS. To opt-out reply 'STOP'"`

I am assuming that `MessagingResponse()` is a class, like so:

```
class MessagingResponse:
    def __init__(self,message):
        self.message = message
```

If so, `resp.message("Your already subscribed")` will throw an error; the correct syntax is `resp.message = "Your already subscribed"`.

Final code (with a few modifications):

**EDIT:**

As @jpmc26 said, using the csv reader/writer is a better option. There were also some bugs in the previous code. Edited code:

```
def sms_subscription():
    contact_num = request.values.get('From')
    response = request.values.get('Body')
    resp = MessagingResponse("") #you might want to remove the quotes if this throws an error

   #NEW SUBSCRIBERS
    if response.lower() == 'memphis':
       with open('Subscriber_List.csv', 'r+') as subscriber_list:

           for contact in csv.reader(subscriber_list):
               if contact_num in contact:

                   resp.message = "You're already subscribed"
                   return resp

           csv.writer(subscriber_list).writerow([contact_num])
           resp.message = ("Thanks for subscribing to our local coupon book. As we get new deals, we'll notify via SMS. To opt-out reply 'STOP'")
           return resp

    else:
        resp.message = "Be sure to check spelling and for spaces and try again."
        return resp
```

Comment: Question, in your Final Code you suggested:                                                              
           
           contact = contact.replace('\n','')
           contact = contact.replace(' ','')
           for contact in subscriber_list.readlines():
               if contact.replace('\n','') == contact_num:

Dis you mean? contact = contact_num.replace('\n', '')
Because i get an error that says "contact not defined " since its not defined until the for loop that comes a few lines later?

Comment: If the file is a csv file, it should not be read with `readlines`. It should be parsed with a CSV reader. While it works now because there is only one column, you don't want it to break later when more columns are added.

Comment: @Ach1916, I've fixed that problem